# Flexbox image height resize

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having trouble getting my images to resize fully.

Ideally I want the image to resize so that the option fits the screen, currently it only fits the width, why so? Is it possible to get the behavior I wish by just using css, maybe a media query is needed? Scorched over google trying to find a similar problem, but no luck!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

[image: Image is not resized]

To clarify, my problem is that the image is not resized, if the height of the window gets small enough - the header disappears and I get a scroll bar. I want all of the content to scale down, so that no scroll bar is needed.

```css
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    flex: 2 1 auto;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.option {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto 1em;
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.img {
    flex: 1;
}

.title {
    flex: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
}

.desc {
    flex: 0;
}

.header {
    flex: 2;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            Fusce pellentesque ante.
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="option">
                <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
                <p class="title">Proin hendrerit.</p>
                <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla non lacus tincidunt suscipit. Nam nec arcu a erat convallis.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
                <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
                <p class="title">Nullam at.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut congue eros. Aenean sit amet quam efficitur, lacinia ligula ac.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
                <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
                <p class="title">Sed nec.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porttitor nisi mauris, ac interdum tellus pulvinar id. Morbi non molestie</p>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
                <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
                <p class="title">Morbi in.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non rutrum arcu, ac posuere odio. Nunc in dolor eget nisi.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
                <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
                <p class="title">Mauris ac.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pulvinar orci non consectetur accumsan. Aenean posuere, felis commodo congue pulvinar.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Quisque venenatis volutpat dictum. Praesent.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5mfon1e2/)**

Comment: I've added a fiddle demo for easier debugging. Can you edit to explain more clearly what the problem is? it looks to me like the width is the problem, but you state otherwise.

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you expect? how much of the screen height do you want the option box to take? You want to display only one option on the screen at a time?

Comment: @isherwood My goal is that header, content and footer always use 100% of the available height, currently is grows fine, but stops shrinking as the image is height is not changing :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you want. If this is the right answer! Here is what i did.

- give the container class of height and width a 100% and set display to `flex` and `flex-direction: column` so header, footer and content class get aligned vertically.
- Now, if you set content class `flex` prorperty to `1` it will take rest of width and height.
- give option class a property of `display: flex` and set `flex-direction: column` so image and the title and description get aligned vertically.
- by assign `min-height` of 30px to the title and p in the options, rest of the space can be assigned to image, which I hope is what you want.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.content .option {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content .option img {
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
  width: 100%;
}
.content .option p {
  height: 20px;
}

.content .option p:nth-child(2) {
  height: 40px;
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 30px;
}

.header {
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Fusce pellentesque ante.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Proin hendrerit.</p>
      <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla non lacus tincidunt suscipit. Nam nec arcu a erat convallis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Nullam at.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut congue eros. Aenean sit amet quam efficitur, lacinia ligula ac.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Sed nec.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porttitor nisi mauris, ac interdum tellus pulvinar id. Morbi non molestie</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Morbi in.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non rutrum arcu, ac posuere odio. Nunc in dolor eget nisi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Mauris ac.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pulvinar orci non consectetur accumsan. Aenean posuere, felis commodo congue pulvinar.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Quisque venenatis volutpat dictum. Praesent.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effot, but this is not what I am looking for. Will update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: post has been edited. sorry i didn't put edit summery.

Answer (score -1):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aqua;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header,
.footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: brown;
}

img {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Fusce pellentesque ante.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Proin hendrerit.</p>
      <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla non lacus tincidunt suscipit. Nam nec arcu a erat convallis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Nullam at.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut congue eros. Aenean sit amet quam efficitur, lacinia ligula ac.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Sed nec.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porttitor nisi mauris, ac interdum tellus pulvinar id. Morbi non molestie</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Morbi in.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non rutrum arcu, ac posuere odio. Nunc in dolor eget nisi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <p class="title">Mauris ac.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pulvinar orci non consectetur accumsan. Aenean posuere, felis commodo congue pulvinar.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Quisque venenatis volutpat dictum. Praesent.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is not being resized when the height gets smaller :(